# Oracle datetime format in dart language

Tags: dart, flutter

I get from API a json object with datetime field in format:

```
"date": "6/23/2018 12:00:00 AM",
```

How to transform it to valid date time object in Dart?

While parsing it I get an error

**Invalid date format**

```
class User {
  int id;

  DateTime date;


  User({this.id,this.date});
    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      id: json['id'],
      date: DateTime.parse(json['date'])
    );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  final dateRegExp =
      RegExp(r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (AM|PM)');

  var match = dateRegExp.firstMatch('6/23/2018 12:00:00 AM');
  var result = DateTime(
    int.parse(match[3]),
    int.parse(match[1]),
    int.parse(match[2]),
    int.parse(match[4]) + (match[7] == 'AM' ? 0 : 12),
    int.parse(match[5]),
    int.parse(match[6]),
  );
  print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simpler way by using this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy). It tries to mimic the simplicity of [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

To get the DateTime object

```
DateTime d = Jiffy.parse("6/23/2018 12:00:00 AM", pattern: "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").dateTime;
```

You can also format it

```
Jiffy.parse("6/23/2018 12:00:00 AM", pattern: "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format("yyyy, MM dd"); // 2018, 06 23

// You can also use default formats
Jiffy.parse("6/23/2018 12:00:00 AM", pattern: "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").yMMMEdjm; // Sat, Jun 23, 2018 12:00 AM
```